# asp:label text content not displaying as it's

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, label, htmlgenericcontrol

Hotel in Reethi Rah's North Male Atoll neighborhood with 3 restaurants

Wonder of Indian Ocean

One&Only Reethi Rah, surrounded by the crystal blue wonders of the Indian Ocean, is a superb all-villa resort that offers an unrivalled level of style, choice and personalised exploration.

Swimming and tennis

In addition to 2 outdoor swimming pools, One&Only Reethi Rah features 3 restaurants, a marina, and a children's club.

DVD players/iPod docks

Guestrooms open to balconies with ocean, sea or garden views and feature beds with Tempur-Pedic mattresses and televisions with premium cable  channels.

```
   <asp:Label ID="lblResortInfo"  runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**when i assign the above content in asp:label it's showing like this**

Hotel in Reethi Rah's North Male Atoll neighborhood with 3 restaurants Wonder of Indian Ocean One&Only Reethi Rah, surrounded by the crystal blue wonders of the Indian Ocean, is a superb all-villa resort that offers an unrivalled level of style, choice and personalised exploration. Swimming and tennis In addition to 2 outdoor swimming pools, One&Only Reethi Rah features 3 restaurants, a marina, and a children's club. DVD players/iPod docks Guestrooms open to balconies with ocean, sea or garden views and feature beds with Tempur-Pedic mattresses and televisions with premium cable channels

**but i want the same structure of content which i mentioned in the top.
pls help me to solve this**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting pre tag around the label

```
 <pre>
 <asp:Label ID="lblResortInfo" runat="server"></asp:Label>
 </pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the label a style of `white-space: pre-line`.

(You could also use a `<pre>` element around the label, but then the output looks different.)